# check if tr element's class name start with a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to check if a `<tr>` element has a class name that starts with a certain value by doing:

```
$('tr[class^="value"]')
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It [appears to work](http://jsfiddle.net/YmdFD/). HTML sample?

Comment: Is the class something like `something value123 blah`?

Comment: Do you have multiple classes on the element? Maybe this one isn't first.

Comment: Did you guys try it for tr elements? I got something like this http://jsfiddle.net/y4M3B/. Any idea why "It didn't work" also got printed out?

Comment: @user765368: And therein lies the problem! `<tr>` elements *can't have text for children*. You need to put the content inside a table cell, `<td>`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/y4M3B/1/

Comment: in future, to check if your query matches, check the length ... ie $('tr').length

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i < classNames.length; i++) {

        // check if the class starts with the value
        if (classNames[i].substr(0, 5) === "value") {
            return true;
        }

        // or you could use a regex
        if (/^value/.test(classNames[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}).each(...);
```

---

Why don't you try using [the `hasClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)?

```
$('tr').hasClass('value');
```

Comment: the value of the class is not an exact string. It just start with a certain pattern. For example it could be myClass1, myClass2, myClass23, myClass654. I want to find out if the class value starts with "myClass".

Comment: Thanks, this should work too, but $('tr[class^="value"]') actually works (see above). I have no idea why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be that you have the tr element and just want to check whether it has a class starting with a certain value, so:

```
var value = 'whatever';
var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + value);
if (re.test(tr.className)) {
  // tr has a class name starting with value
}
```

Or do you want to select all TRs that have a class starting with a particular value? You may be able to use querySelectorAll for that, if your TRs only have one class:

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr[class^=' + value + ']');
```

Or in plain javascript:

```
var el, els = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + value);
var result = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i++) {
    el = els[i];

    if (re.test(el.className)) {
        result.push(el);
    }
}
// do something with result array
```

*result* is an array of matching TRs in document order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Hristo** suggestion combined with jQuery custom expressions if you'll use it heavily, but becareful because I made benchmarks and it can be easily 3-4 times slowly.

Example:

```
$.expr[':'].classStarts = function(elem, index, match) {
    var classNames = elem.className.split(/\s+/);

    /* getting only the value passed inside the parentheses */
    var filter = match[0].match(/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/, '')[1];
    for (var i = -1, _len = classNames.length; ++i < _len; ) {

        if (classNames[i].substr(0, filter.length) === filter) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
};
// USING
$('div:classStarts(myClass)').css('color', 'red');
```